# Windows 7 Native Look for .NET ListView

Tags: .net, windows, listview, themes

Currently, my ListViews look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that Windows 7 native look below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered here: [How to get Windows native look for the .NET TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131534/how-to-get-windows-native-look-for-the-net-treeview)

The given solution works for both for the ListView and the TreeView.

```
public class NativeListView : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private extern static int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string pszSubAppName,
                                        string pszSubIdList);

    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
        base.CreateHandle();

        SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "explorer", null);
    }
}
```