# How to get Windows native look for the .NET TreeView?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, treeview

[image: Trees]

When using the TreeView component in .NET, I get the look of the left tree.
How can I get the look of the right tree (Windows Native Look) for my .NET TreeView?

What I especially want to get is the "triangle" node handles and the blue "bubble" selection square.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to P/Invoke to call [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827.aspx) passing the window handle of the tree and use "explorer" as the theme.

Paste the following code into a new class in your project, compile, and use this custom control instead of the built-in `TreeView` control.

#### C#:

```cs
public class NativeTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
{
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private extern static int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string pszSubAppName,
                                            string pszSubIdList);

    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
        base.CreateHandle();
        SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "explorer", null);
    }
}
```

#### VB.NET:

```vb
Public Class NativeTreeView : Inherits TreeView

    Private Declare Unicode Function SetWindowTheme Lib "uxtheme.dll"
        (hWnd As IntPtr, pszSubAppName As String, pszSubIdList As String) As Integer

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
        MyBase.CreateHandle()
        SetWindowTheme(Me.Handle, "Explorer", Nothing)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that this trick also works exactly the same way for the `ListView` control.

Comment: @cody thanks for the edit I'm on my phone today so this was from memory!

Comment: Sure. The other answers were just wrong, and I didn't see the point in posting my own answer just for a code sample, when you'd already gotten the hard part. [It seems like you're on your phone a lot. You really ought to invest in a computer. Makes it much easier to write code. :-)]

Comment: I've try to convert that code into vb.net and tested it, but it was still the same treeview.

Comment: @dave No, that's no problem

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Illumi is correct, I confirm that in Win8 this doesn't work unless you run your program as administrator, strange why is this bihaveour?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes my mistake, sorry, it really works.

Comment: IMPORTANT: When I move the cursor over the items, it not changes the style like windows explorer, is there some sendmessage or some P/Invoke or override for that

Comment: @Codigos All caps is considered rude. You have a new question. Please ask it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan TreeView "over" effects is not applied when I use this method, I saw Windows Explorer has a effect to move the cursor over the items (like ListView), when I call native setWindowTheme with ListView, it has its effects (hover effects), but TreeView does not have.

Comment: @Codigos You are mistaken in doing this in a comment to another question. Ask a question. Give lots of detail. Screenshots are great for this type of question.

Comment: Thanks for this David, I've been struggling with a lot of OwnerDrawAll for TreeView to achieve simmilar look as Explorer. And then I found this lol

Comment: Hi, I know this is a bit late but can i ask how can i change the color of it? It's default color is black i want it to be white.

Comment: @Unknown Which part of the tree view control is black for you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the icon that replaces the plus minus. ( > ^ )

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can i change it to White? How?

Comment: @Unknown The entire point of using the system theme is that it is consistent across all applications. If you want to change the way the control is painted you need to take over painting it yourself.