# Windows 7 style treeview in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, styling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Windows native look for the .NET TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131534/how-to-get-windows-native-look-for-the-net-treeview)

I'm wondering if it is possible to style my Windows Forms treeview using the Vista / Windows 7 style when available. If it is running in older versions of windows then I would expect the regular treeview style to be used.

Is this possible using a manifest or will it require more detailed customization or the use of a third party control?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SetWindowTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
SetWindowTheme(treeView.Handle, "EXPLORER", NULL);
```

Comment: +1 this is how to do it. There's a bit more detail in the duplicate answer linked above.