# Windows 7 styled TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Windows native look for the .NET TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131534/how-to-get-windows-native-look-for-the-net-treeview)
>   [Windows 7 style treeview in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408163/windows-7-style-treeview-in-windows-forms)

How can I create a TreeView like the one in the image below? (The highlighting with gradient and the nodes points)
Tehnology used: WinForms with C#2010
[image]

Comment: You probably need to make a custom control to get this on XP, if that's waht you mean. Just as an aside, if you used WPF you can simply force the Aero theme on your users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131534/how-to-get-windows-native-look-for-the-net-treeview

Comment: Woops, you're probably right @DanielA.White. I looked at this from a more cross-OS aspect!

Comment: @rudi_visser I am using Windows Seven.