# C# WinForms TreeView remove Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: c#, treeview

I need to have a TreeView with only vertical scrollbar.

I tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/4aa4dade-53a2-4e2e-a8b4-b4980da1f39c/) but it doesnt work, the resulting scrollbar doesnt do anything at all.

I tried the opposite (scrollable to true and disable horizontal scrollbar with that user32.dll function) - it doesnt work, when i add long enough stuff to the TreeView the scrollbar shows again...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try turning on the **TVS_NOHSCROLL** window style on the treeview control. To do so you have to extend the standard TreeView control with a custom TreeView like this one :

```
public class NoHScrollTree : TreeView {
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
get {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.Style |= 0x8000; // TVS_NOHSCROLL
    return cp;
}
} }
```

Comment: Here's a ready-to-go class which has a "HorizontalScrollbar" property that can be set in the designer: https://pastebin.com/dnbGfiqp

Comment: It's work fine , But i need horizontal scroll when node text exceed the control. https://ibb.co/ibnCic

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to get the look and feel like Windows Vista and 7 native tree view, then you should follow this,

[How to get Windows native look for the .NET TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131534/how-to-get-windows-native-look-for-the-net-treeview)

SetWindowTheme is necessary. Then the horizontal scroll bar won't appear.

It works on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Nope i just wanted what i asked for, but still thanks for valueable info! ;)