# How can I decrease the width of indent in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ListView in `ListView.View = View.Details` that is implemented as directory navigation. I'm using NativeMethods implementation from [C# Show File and Folder Icons in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791149/c-sharp-show-file-and-folder-icons-in-listview) to display folder icons next to each item in the list. I also use `ListViewItem.IndentCount` to indent items in order to make directory structure clear; such that the top list item is the root, drive path, with no indentation. Each child folder increases in indent; code below.

```
foldersListView.Items.Clear();
//ListView items display in the order added, so we need a LIFO (Last in First out) Collection in order to add the root directory first
Stack<ListViewItem> parentDirectories = new Stack<ListViewItem>();
//Get current directory    
DirectoryInfo currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
DirectoryInfo parentDirectory = currentDirectory;

do {
    parentDirectories.Push(new ListViewItem(parentDirectory.Name);
} while ((parentDirectory = parentDirectory.Parent) != null);

int indent = 0;
while (parentDirectories.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewItem item = parentDirectories.Pop();
    item.IndentCount = indent++;
    foldersListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The above works great, but the issue I'm running into is the indent width is much too high, such that once the user is 4 or 5 directories down, the folders are running off the right side of the ListView. I understand that the indent width is specifically the width of the image/icon that is included with each item. I'm wondering if it's possible to decrease the width of the indent without changing the size of the images/icons.

To be clear, I have working indent, but I'd like each `indentCount` to move the `ListViewItem` less than it is.

Comment: The Win32 Control generates the indentation. The .NET ListView just asks (P/Invokes SendMessage with `LVM_SETITEM`) the SysListView32 to do it (BTW, I don't see how the code you posted here can replicate the layout you described) -- The ListView usually shows the content of a Directory. The Directory structure is more commonly visually replicated with a TreeView (meaning, if you go outside well-trodden paths, you'll have to create your own; here, paint the Items yourself, as you see fit)