# Draw system focus rectangle c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, gdi

How can I draw a system focus rectangle using gdi, C#? I'm mainly interested in the glass effect focus rectangle found in the common listview control on Windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need an exact effect? any screen shot to show what you want?

Comment: Not exact I was hopping that there is some system function that will provide me system specific focus recangle . Like in this question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086682/windows-7-native-look-for-net-listview'

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162274.aspx

Comment: Thanks I found this based on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014816/visualstylerenderer-and-themes-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a `Panel` to treat as a `ListViewItem` and drawing on this panel to demonstrate what should be done, it looks almost like the focused entry in a ListView used in Windows 7.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {            
        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush brush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(100, 204, 222,246), Color.FromArgb(190,220,255) , 90))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush,new Rectangle(2,2,panel1.ClientSize.Width - 4, panel1.ClientSize.Height - 4));
        }
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(133, 164, 202), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(1,1, panel1.ClientSize.Width - 2, panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2), 
            Color.FromArgb(100,220,240,255), 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            Color.FromArgb(100,220,240,255), 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            Color.FromArgb(100,204,222,250), 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        e.Graphics.DrawString("I love .NET", panel1.Font, Brushes.Black, panel1.ClientRectangle, sf);
    }
```

And here is the screen shot to compare the both entries:
[image]